# Ballerina HMAC SHA256 not generating expected results

Tags: ballerina

I have a vendor who authenticates their posts to a web hook with an HMAC SHA256. When I attempt to validate that signature with Ballerina, I'm unable to match the signature.

In order to test and observe, I've created a fictitious private key and payload on CodeBeautify, then a straightforward implementation of generating the same in Ballerina. Attached is the Ballerina code; what am I missing in this use case?

At run time, the signatures to compare are rendered:
Ballerina-generated signature: [33,1,109,19,199,246,135,242,0,50,145,48,243,133,137,180,127,109,85,52,231,239,247,107,22,220,97,67,65,131,121,172]
CodeBeautify-generated signature: [57,54,57,52,100,101,101,51,55,101,57,50,50,49,53,52,56,102,48,51,53,97,99,97,54,52,99,52,99,97,51,48,51,97,50,48,98,102,99,57,49,54,54,49,100,55,50,51,51,100,55,97,51,101,53,50,53,99,55,49,48,102,99,52]
Regenerated CodeBeautify Signature: 9694dee37e9221548f035aca64c4ca303a20bfc91661d7233d7a3e525c710fc4

`

```
import ballerina/crypto;
import ballerina/io;

public function main() returns error? {
    // strGeneratedSignature produced with strHMACKey and jsonHMACMessage on https://codebeautify.org/hmac-generator

    string strHMACKey = "f785a0dfd2b63f06caf9205497c67777";
    json jsonHMACMessage = {"message": "Hello Ballerina HMAC"};
    string strGeneratedSignature = "9694dee37e9221548f035aca64c4ca303a20bfc91661d7233d7a3e525c710fc4"; // as generated by CodeBeautify's HMAC tool
    byte[] generatedSignatureBytes = strGeneratedSignature.toBytes();
    string strBody = jsonHMACMessage.toString();
    byte[] data = strBody.toBytes();
    byte[] hmacKeyBytes = strHMACKey.toBytes();
    byte[] hmacSignatureBytes = check crypto:hmacSha256(data, hmacKeyBytes);
    io:println(`Ballerina-generated signature: `, hmacSignatureBytes);
    io:println(`CodeBeautify-generated signature: `, generatedSignatureBytes);
    
    string strRegeneratedSignature = check string:fromBytes(generatedSignatureBytes);
    // string strBallerinaSignature = check string:fromBytes(hmacSignatureBytes);

    io:println(`Regenerated CodeBeautify Signature: `, strRegeneratedSignature);
    // io:println(`Ballerina Signature: `, strBallerinaSignature);

 }
```

`
Please note also that I'm able to get and reconstitute the CodeBeautify signature bytes, but not the Ballerina-generated byte array-attempting to do so results in "error: FailedToDecodeBytes {"message":"array contains invalid UTF-8 byte value"}"

Answer (score 3):

It seems the reason is the mismatch in the space after the `:` in the given json payload.

`json jsonHMACMessage = {"message": "Hello Ballerina HMAC"};` is a json object in Ballerina and the space after `:` will be removed when you convert it to a string.

In codebeautify the input is treated as a string. See the below code example with further explanations.

```
import ballerina/io;
import ballerina/crypto;

public function main() returns error? {

    string strHMACKey = "f785a0dfd2b63f06caf9205497c67777";
    json jsonHMACMessage = {"message": "Hello Ballerina HMAC"}; //This is a json object in Ballerina.
    string stringConvertedMessage = jsonHMACMessage.toString(); //When converting above json object to string the space after : is gone.
    io:println(stringConvertedMessage); //Output is {"message":"Hello Ballerina HMAC"} - Note no space after :
    byte[] hmacSignatureBytes = check crypto:hmacSha256(stringConvertedMessage.toBytes(), strHMACKey.toBytes());
    io:println(hmacSignatureBytes.toBase16()); //Output is 21016d13c7f687f200329130f38589b47f6d5534e7eff76b16dc6143418379ac
    //You will get the same above output if you convert {"message":"Hello Ballerina HMAC"} (note without space after :) using codebeautify hmac generator

    //Instead of you define the message as a string in Ballerina you will get same output as the string input in codebeatity
    string stringHMACMessage = "{\"message\": \"Hello Ballerina HMAC\"}";
    byte[] hmacSignatureBytes2 = check crypto:hmacSha256(stringHMACMessage.toBytes(), strHMACKey.toBytes());
    io:println(hmacSignatureBytes2.toBase16()); //Output is 9694dee37e9221548f035aca64c4ca303a20bfc91661d7233d7a3e525c710fc4
    //You will get the same above output if you convert {"message": "Hello Ballerina HMAC"} (note with space after :) using codebeautify hmac generator
 }
```

Comment: Thanks Anupama, that explains it. Unfortunately, I don't control the way the data comes over into the web hook (it's a JSON payload, probably signed as a string before posting.) I'll see if I can convert to string and find a pattern to re-inject the missing spaces.

Comment: In that case,  without extracting the json payload and then converting to string you should be able to retrieve text payload directly and then get the hmac from that string.

Comment: What Anupama suggested is also what is done in the WebSub module (which could be used instead if the webhook is WebSub-compliant), where the payload is extracted as text (https://github.com/ballerina-platform/module-ballerina-websub/blob/v2.5.0/ballerina/request_processor.bal#L84) to verify the signature (HMAC) first. If the verification is successful, then the relevant payload extraction method (based on content type) is called (https://github.com/ballerina-platform/module-ballerina-websub/blob/v2.5.0/ballerina/request_processor.bal#L99).

Comment: Alternatively, as the second step, lang library functions such as `value:fromJsonString` or `value:fromJsonStringWithType` can be used to parse the string in JSON format.

Comment: Thanks to you both! I've been successful with reconstituting test payloads but not the more complex vendor payload. I'll try the alternative approaches you suggest and get back to you.